# Vendor Machine API's Postman Collection Issue

Tags: typescript, rest, postman, localhost, nestjs

## I am trying to create a postman collection for a Vendor machine API but when I try to send a login request `localhost:3000/auth/login` I get connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Could the below error be the one making postman not respond to endpoint requests or is there a way of providing the port 3030?

Comment: The problem is not postman its your server! You need to provide some logs from your server. If a read your screen correctly your port is 80. Try  just localhost

Comment: Are you actually running your server? The test most likely runs a server in memory instead of making a full http request. Your `main.ts` should have a `app.listen(3000)` which is how you tell the server to start on port 3000 and you need to run `nest build && node dist/main` or `nest start` or `nest start --watch` to actually run the server on your local machine

Comment: @Torsten Thanks very much for your help. I realized that I had indicated PORT=1003 in my .env file, so it should be localhost:1003/... and the default is localhost:3000/... if nothing is provided in the .env file. So I was using port 3000 when I had a port already specified in the .env file i.e. 1003 :)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thanks too, you helped me solve my problem. Instead of `app.listen(3000)` I had `PORT=1003` in the .env file. So using localhost:1003/... worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Torsten and Jay McDoniel. They helped me realize that I was doing it the wrong way! I had indicated `PORT=1003` in my .env file, so I ought to have used `localhost:1003/...` The default is `localhost:3000/...` that is to be used when no port is provided in the .env file. So I was using port 3000 when I had a port already specified in the .env file i.e. 1003 :)